# VSCode Microsoft C++ build tools aren't recognized unless vscode is opened via Developer Command Prompt?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

The Microsoft C/C++ extension for VS Code doesn't work with MSVC unless VS Code is opened through the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2019.
It gives the problem

cl.exe : The term 'cl.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- cl.exe /Zi /EHsc /Fe: c:\Users<myname>\setup.vscode\c_cpp_properties.e ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cl.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

But if I open with their dev cmd prmpt, it works fine if I open the folder from there.
Can I set it to work with the normal shortcut, or is there a reason I need to use their cmd prmpt?

Comment: "Developer Command Prompt" shortcut runs a .bat file that adds to `PATH` environment variable the directory where the build tools are installed. You can add them to your system path permanently, if you are so inclined.

Comment: Your question is a non-question as this is part of the documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_create-hello-world . It's right in the first sentence, and is explained in the paragraphs above. "Working as intended."

Comment: @IgorTandetnik where can I find this directory? Is it the one that ends in \bin?

Comment: @BillBob: It can vary. That's why there is a Developer Command Prompt. It's customized to every VC++ install.

Comment: Once you are in Developer Command Prompt, type `where cl`. It'll show you where it finds `cl.exe` on your system.

Comment: @sweenish: I have to install `C++ build tools` from Visual Studio Installer after the installer has been installed. Otherwise, I don't have `cl.exe` on my computer at all.